# INDEX function in phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I need to write a formula into the cell:

```
$formula4 = '=INDEX(Сотни,TRUNC(G2/100)+1)&" "&IF(G2-TRUNC(G2/100)*100<21,INDEX(Единицы,G2-TRUNC(G2/100)*100+1),INDEX(Десятки,TRUNC((G2-TRUNC(G2/100)*100)/10))&" "&INDEX(Единицы,MOD(G2,10)+1))';
```

But unfortunately, I've got an error that function is not right.
Единицы, Сотни and Десятки are names of the columns, under them, I've got strings that have to be written in the direction cell.

Comment: You should share the error message with the rest of the class, and enough code/data for us to reproduce the issue as well.

Comment: I've already found out what was the problem,  the thing is that I have to use cell Arrays instead of row names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing was that we can't use row names in INDEX function(as we can in EXCEL) instead, we must use cell arrays like D2:D22

Comment: I can do that only after 48 hours after posting